# Try to use httpClient.execute(httpGet) but it shows timeout

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I'm using

```
Response = httpClient.execute(httpGet)
```

to get the data back, but sometimes it will take a long time, so Response will show a timeout exception. I want to use the HTTP way to do that and `setHeader`, so as my search on website I only can use `.execute` method.
Could I know if there are some other HTTP ways I can use? Or how could I set the timeout of it? Or how could I ask its data when timeout happens? Thank you.

Comment: Can you post some of your code, this way you will be able to get some good suggestions.

Comment: Are you referring to class [java.net.http.HttpClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.net.http/java/net/http/HttpClient.html) ?